# WPF Datagrid - How to make a change in one row affect other rows

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I have a WPF datagrid that is bound to a collection of Item objects. The datagrid has a checkbox column. I would like to implement it so that when the checkbox is checked/unchecked from any row, all other rows are checked/unchecked. Is there a good MVVM way to do this?

**XAML**

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding MyProperty}" />
    <DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

**C#**

```cs
public class DataGridViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public bool MyProperty { get; set; } // Set all Item.MyProperties when any are set
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on a [Previous Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14971905/643085):

Use this as your data items:

```
public class Selectable<T>: ViewModelBase //ViewModelBase should Implement NotifyPropertyChanged.
{
    private T _model;
    public T Model 
    {   get { return _model; }
        set 
        {
            _model = value;
            NotifyPropertyChange("Model");
        }
    }

    private bool _isSelected;
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return _isSelected; }
        set
        {
            _isSelected = value;
            NotifyPropertyChange("IsSelected");

            if (OnIsSelectedChanged != null)
                OnIsSelectedChanged(this);
        }
    }

    public Action<Selectable<T>> OnIsSelectedChanged;
 }
```

Then change your ViewModel to look like so:

```
public class DataGridViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Selectable<Item>> Items { get; set; }

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
       Items = new ObservableCollection<Selectable<Item>>();

       //Populate the Collection here!

       foreach (var item in Items)
           item.OnIsSelectedChanged = OnItemSelectedChanged;
    }

    private void OnItemSelectedChanged(Selectable<Item> item)
    {
       if (item.IsSelected)
       {
           var itemsToDeselect = Items.Where(x => x != item);

           foreach (var itemToDeselect in itemsToDeselect)
               itemToDeselect.IsSelected = false;
       }
    }
}
```