# How to effectly implement AddRange() for a WPF ListView SelectedItems?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have a `ListView` and I wanted to add some new items to its `ListView.SelectedItems`.
I was using a slow approach:

```
for (int i = beginIndex; i <= endIndex; i++)
{
    myListView.SelectedItems.Add(myObjectList[i]);
}
```

If myListView is empty before add, I could use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21941834/3576052) to add selected items. But in case myListView already has some `SelectedItems`, and I want to add more, I cannot use `ListView.SetSelectedItems()`.

How can I add selected items more effectively? Is there an AddRange() function or a similar method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there an AddRange() function or a similar method?

No.

The `SelectedItems` property of a `ListView` returns an instance of the internal type `SelectedItemCollection` and this one has no `AddRange()` method.

But even it there actually was an `AddRange()` method, what do you think it would do? It would certainly loop over the `IEnumerable` that you pass to it somehow.

There is no more efficient way of iterating through items.