# Custom control with checked objects logic inherited from ListBox wpf

Tags: wpf, checkbox, listbox, controls

I need a custom control such as ListBox, but with checked object logic( can check object(s), can bind to CheckedObjects collection, can switch check mode from "single" to "multiple"). I  started from adding dependency property and RoutedEvents to my controls inherited from ListBoxItem(CheckedListboxItem) and ListBox(CheckedListBox), but I don`t know how to make my CheckedListBox use CheckedListBoxItem instead ListBoxItem.
 Yes, I know about templates, but i can't implement IsChecked property in my Business Objects.
upd. code:

```
public partial class CheckedListBox : ListBox
  {
    public CheckedListBox()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CheckedItemsProperty;
    public static readonly RoutedEvent CheckedChangedEvent;
    public static readonly RoutedEvent ItemCheckedEvent;
    public static readonly RoutedEvent ItemUnCheckedEvent;

    static CheckedListBox()
    {
      CheckedItemsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("CheckedItems", typeof(IList), typeof(CheckedListBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new ArrayList(), new PropertyChangedCallback(OnCheckedItemsChanged)));
      CheckedChangedEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("CheckedChanged", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedPropertyChangedEventHandler<bool>), typeof(CheckedListBoxItem));
      EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(CheckedListBox), CheckedListBoxItem.CheckedEvent,
        new RoutedEventHandler(checkedEventHandler));
      EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(CheckedListBox), CheckedListBoxItem.UnCheckedEvent,
        new RoutedEventHandler(unCheckedEventHandler));
    }

    private static void checkedEventHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      var checkedListBox = (CheckedListBox)sender;
      var item = (CheckedListBoxItem)e.OriginalSource;
      var collection = checkedListBox.CheckedItems;
      collection.Add(item.Content);
    }

    private static void unCheckedEventHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      var checkedListBox = (CheckedListBox)sender;
      var item = (CheckedListBoxItem)e.OriginalSource;
      var collection = checkedListBox.CheckedItems;
      collection.Remove(item.Content);
    }

    public static event DependencyPropertyChangedEventHandler CheckedItemsChanged;

    public event RoutedEventHandler ItemChecked
    {
      add { AddHandler(ItemCheckedEvent, value); }
      remove { RemoveHandler(ItemCheckedEvent, value); }
    }
    public event RoutedEventHandler ItemUnChecked
    {
      add { AddHandler(ItemUnCheckedEvent, value); }
      remove { RemoveHandler(ItemUnCheckedEvent, value); }
    }
    public IList CheckedItems
    {
      get { return (IList)GetValue(CheckedItemsProperty); }
      set { SetValue(CheckedItemsProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void OnCheckedItemsChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
      var checkedListBox = (CheckedListBox)sender;
      var args = new RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<IList>((IList)e.OldValue, (IList)e.NewValue);
      args.RoutedEvent = CheckedListBox.CheckedChangedEvent;
      checkedListBox.RaiseEvent(args);
    }

    protected override bool IsItemItsOwnContainerOverride(object item)
    {
      return (item is CheckedListBoxItem);
    }

    protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
    {
      return new CheckedListBoxItem();
    }
  }

  public class CheckedListBoxItem : ListBoxItem
  {
    public static DependencyProperty IsCheckedProperty;
    public static readonly RoutedEvent CheckChangedEvent;
    public static readonly RoutedEvent CheckedEvent;
    public static readonly RoutedEvent UnCheckedEvent;

    public bool IsChecked
    {
      get { return (bool)GetValue(IsCheckedProperty); }
      set { SetValue(IsCheckedProperty, value); }
    }

    public event RoutedPropertyChangedEventHandler<bool> CheckChanged
    {
      add { AddHandler(CheckChangedEvent, value); }
      remove { RemoveHandler(CheckChangedEvent, value); }
    }


    static CheckedListBoxItem()
    {
      IsCheckedProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsChecked", typeof(bool), typeof(CheckedListBoxItem), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnCheckChanged)));
      CheckChangedEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("CheckChanged", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedPropertyChangedEventHandler<bool>), typeof(CheckedListBoxItem));
      CheckedEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("Checked", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(CheckedListBoxItem));
      UnCheckedEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("UnChecked", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(CheckedListBoxItem));
    }

    private static void OnCheckChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
      var checkedListBoxItem = (CheckedListBoxItem)sender;
      var oldValue = (bool)e.OldValue;
      var newValue = (bool)e.NewValue;
      if ((bool)e.NewValue && !(bool)e.OldValue)
      {
        var argch = new RoutedEventArgs(CheckedListBoxItem.CheckedEvent);
        checkedListBoxItem.RaiseEvent(argch);
      }
      else if (!(bool)e.NewValue && (bool)e.OldValue)
      {
        var argun = new RoutedEventArgs(CheckedListBoxItem.UnCheckedEvent);
        checkedListBoxItem.RaiseEvent(argun);
      }
      var args = new RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<bool>(oldValue, newValue);
      args.RoutedEvent = CheckedListBoxItem.CheckChangedEvent;
      checkedListBoxItem.RaiseEvent(args);
    }
  }
```

Comment: `but i can't implement IsChecked property in my Business Objects.` - IsChecked (or IsSelected) should be a ViewModel concern, not a Business Model concern. See [This Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14971905/643085)

Comment: To @HighCore, sorry, I mean ViewModel of course. Problem is that objects already in collections and this is legacy code. Also if a convert my ICollection<object> to ICollection<WrapedObject> i don't able anymore listen changes in original objects' properties. So i think custom control is more useful decision

Comment: @dev hedgehog, code added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make your CheckBoxList use CheckBoxListItem you should consider overriding the method GetContainerForItemOverride(). Take a look at this:

```
  public class ForceDirectedItemsControl : ItemsControl
  {
      protected override bool IsItemItsOwnContainerOverride(object item)
      {
          return (item is ForceDirectedItem);
      }

      protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
      {
          return new ForceDirectedItem();
      }
  }
```

Comment: first if i add CheckBox in ListBox.ItemTemplate, i can't use DisplayMemeberPath, because ItemTemplate used. And how i can notify about adding item to my IList CheckedItems collection? DependencyProperty don't change when i add item to collection. Also INotifyPropertyChanged dont'help.