# Get Item from Checked Change event (RoutedEventArgs) WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, events

I want to know if I can get the Item source item from a checked change event in WPF?

XAML

```
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Active, Mode=TwoWay}" Checked="CheckBox_Checked" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></CheckBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Sample C# (on the lines of correct answer.. I hope)

```
     private void CheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        **// Its not e.source, most events it's e.item...but the checked event doesn't use this..**

        Customer c = e.Source as Customer;



        if(c != null)
        .....
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you want that for? [UI is NOT Data](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14382137/643085). If your checkbox is already Bound to an underlying object, why not just listen for the property change in the underlying object? what are you trying to do?

Comment: Because the underlying object is from a ObservableCollection and I want to listen out for individual property events i.e. when the active checkbox is checked which the collection won't allow (easily) but I also need the row data as well

Comment: the UI is not the right place to put whatever business logic you need. Either listen for the `PropertyChanged` event in your data item, or put your logic in a delegate and call that in the setter of the `Active` property. Or use something like a [`Selectable<T>`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14971905/643085) approach.

Comment: I agree that the logic needs to go into the ViewModel, but he selected<t> wont work as it only selects the row on first click of the row and not on the checkbox. Good idea with the delegate, but I will be setting this in the model.. not the viewmodel.. again incorrect use of MVVM?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, Assuming you are not following MVVM

```
  private void CheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      bool IsActive = (sender as CheckBox).IsChecked;
      if(IsActive)
      {
         Active;
      }
    }
```

Comment: I am following MVVM but I have realised that getting the individual property inside a ObservableCollection in a ViewModel isnt easy and will take a lot a code to do what I need. so this is a quick (but messy substitute) will have a look

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like  [Refernece](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/18821.wpfmvvm-binding-the-ischecked-property-of-a-checkbox-to-several-other-checkboxes.aspx)

[Reference 2](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/461527/MVVM-WPF-Checkbox-checked-programatically)

Viewmodel

```
private bool _isactive;

    public bool IsActive
    {
        get { return _isactive; }
        set
        {
            _isactive = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => IsActive);
        }
    }
```

if you want get the eventargs in mvvm . use Relay Command or Icommand

xaml

```
<CheckBox x:Name="chkbox" Command="{Binding CommandName}"
                      CommandParameter="{parameter}"/>
```

handle the command do necessary action.

Comment: This syntax makes sense and how I would want to do it, but the property  _isactive wouldn't be part of the current DataContext. So basically, not part of the collection. So to do the above, I would need to use RelativeSource I guess?

Comment: ya use relative source if source binding not part of current datacontext. Try the reference will help . or post more code i will help in u way i can