# How to Select All check box together in WPF datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

my  wpf data grid is,

```
<dg:DataGrid.Columns >
    <dg:DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
            <CheckBox Content=" Slect All" Click="CheckBox_Click" />
        </dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
        <dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox Name="chkSelectAll"   Margin="45 2 0 0" Click="chkSelectAll_Click" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </dg:DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <dg:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Edit Row"  >
        <dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Content="Edit" Click="Button_Click" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </dg:DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <dg:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Delete Row">
        <dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Content="Delete" Click="DeleteButton_Click" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </dg:DataGridTemplateColumn>
</dg:DataGrid.Columns>
```

on click of this Select all checkbox I need to get all checkbox as selected/Unselect.
Can any one help me to get it done. Also one more thing , Dynamicaly I am populating the data to the datgrid.

--
thanks

Comment: put an `bool IsSelected` property on your data item and bind to that, or use a `Selectable<T>` approach as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14971905/643085).

Comment: can any one please show the example here, I tried with the bool IsSelected property  but its not working for me.:(

Comment: post the code you already tried and a specific explanation of how it's "not working" (are you getting an exception?) and then we can help you. Otherwise your question is likely to be closed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Bind the checkBox **`IsChecked`** property to header checkBox using **`ElementName`**:

```
<dg:DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
        <CheckBox Content=" Slect All" x:Name="headerCheckBox" />
    </dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
    <dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Name="chkSelectAll" Margin="45 2 0 0"
                      IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=headerCheckBox, 
                                          Mode=OneWay}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</dg:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```